# Copy all files to their parent folder

Tags: shell-script

I need to move all the videos files in a file tree to their parent folders, for example:

origin:

```
A--sub1--file1
         file2
   sub2--file3
       --file4
   sub3--file5
B--sub1--file1
         file2
   sub2--file3
       --file4
   sub3--file5
   ...
```

what I need:

```
A--file1
   file2
   file3
   file4
   file5
B--file1
   file2
   file3
   file4
   file5
   ...
```

I am trying to use shell script, and what I am up to is:

```
for file in `find -name *avi`; do something ; done
```

I would like to use the file name I get from `find -name *avi` to get its parent folder's path, which is the part before the second last '/'. But I don't know how to achieve it using shell script, regex may help but I have totally no idea how, any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -name "*.avi" |
while read -r file; do
    mv -v "$file" "${file%/*/*}"
done
```

Comment: thanks a lot, exactly what I need, and now I understand better about the string operation "%"

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/start

Comment: thx for link as well